# Passing local variable with name of a global variable isn't possible in JS?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope, local-variables

```
foo = "foobar";
var bar = function(){
    var foo = foo || "";
    return foo;
}
bar();`
```

This code gives a result empty string. Why cannot JS reassign a local variable with same name as a global variable? In other programming languages the expected result is of course "foobar", why does JS behave like that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's because you declared a local variable with the same name - and it masks the global variable. So when you write `foo` you refer to the local variable. That's true even if you write it before the declaration of that local variable, variables in JavaScript are function-scoped. However, you can use the fact that global variables are properties of the global object (`window`):

```
var foo = window.foo || "";
```

`window.foo` refers to the global variable here.

Comment: Thanks! Though globals in eval statements don't show up directly under the window object, but not many use eval statements.

Comment: @user3015682: Well, as I said [a while ago](https://palant.de/2009/02/06/five-wrong-reasons-to-use-eval-in-an-extension) - there are very few valid reasons to use eval.

Comment: Well one cool thing about eval is that they are a good way to test out isolated code snippets very quickly and easily, but that's for development.

Answer (score 2):

Once interpreter sees `var foo` it assumes `foo` is a local variable. Why? The answer is simple: because that's how this language has been constructed. (and no, it is not the only language that works this way)