# How get access to some variables with same names by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've got 3 variables with same names (value). I'd like read it all from internal function (f2).
Help me write code for next cases (see alerting blocks)

```
var value = "global"
function f1() {
    var value = "external";

    function f2() {
        var value = "internal";

        alert(any code 1?) // global
        alert(any code 2?) // external
        alert(any code 3?) // internal
    }
}
```

For example how it works by ActionScript:

```
var _value = "global"

function f1() {
    var _value = "external";

    function f2() {
        var ext=_value
        var _value = "internal";

        trace(_root._value)     // works: global
        trace(ext)              // works: external
        trace(_value)           // works: internal
    }
    f2()
}
f1()
```

or ActionScript by object activation (but I know JavaScript denied access to this object):

```
var _value = "global"

function f1() {
    var _value = "external";

    function f2() {
        _value // do link to object activation (by f1)
        var _value = "internal";

        trace(_root._value)     // works: global
        trace(this._value)      // works: external
        trace(_value)           // works: internal      
    }
    f2()
}
f1()
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186171/passing-local-variable-with-name-of-a-global-variable-isnt-possible-in-js

Comment: I think you should use different nane for them. The inner variable or the narrow scope variable should have shorter name. If you really can't figure out alternative name, you can name the inner most variable with `_value`

Comment: Look up the question in the link. The thing is, JavaScript doesn't really have a mechanism for separating scopes this way: global objects are always accessible and they will get ovewritten if you try to declare a variable with the same name inside a function.

Comment: Thanx, but it's no practises, but theoretical question. For example for ActionScript it has easy deciding

Comment: Praveen Kumar, it is not duplicate. Because your link say only about root scoupe, but not about internal function

Comment: I change my answer. Is steel duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

The same names will get overridden. But for global, I guess you can use `window.`:

```
var value = "global"
function f1() {
    var value = "external";

    function f2() {
        var value = "internal";

        alert(window.value)  // works: global
        alert(any code 2?)   // no idea: external
        alert(value)         // works: internal
    }
}
```

It is interesting to note that, `f2()` can be accessed **only** from `f1()`! As [Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh) commented, a small change will give you access to everything:

```
var value = "global"
function f1(value) {
    var global_value = value;
    var value = "external";

    function f2(value) {
        var internal_value = value;
        var value = "internal";

        alert(window.value)     // works: global
        alert(global_value)     // works: global
        alert(internal_value)   // works: external
        alert(value)            // works: internal
    }
}
```

Comment: i believe you can pass `external` variable as function parameter, since `f2()` can be called only from `f1()`

Comment: @Rajesh Updated and credited. Thanks.

Comment: No it's not. It's strongly variable (not parameter). And it's possible called from root (it ease if f1 return link to f2 to root)

Comment: @user5555232 Can you clarify what you are saying?

Comment: alert(this.value)     // works: global
alert(global_value)     // undefined // no works: global
alert(internal_value)   // undefined // no works: external
alert(value)            // works: internal

Comment: @user5555232 How did you call `f2()`. I can give you an updated code?

Comment: You just use parameter for function. It isn't right for my task. Thanx for try help me )))
I wish understand some theoretical question of JS. 
How I say in ActionScript this case has easy answer. But I don't understand how it possible for JS?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I cann't use chat, but I try explain by into new edition of my question. See above

Comment: @user5555232 I am still thinking on how to solve. http://output.jsbin.com/temegihinu